# Raspberry Pi WiFi hotspot - Assign address from Wireless network IP range to eth0

Tags: linux, networking, hostapd

I have hostapd and dnsmasq running on a RPi which I have configured to broadcast a local wifi network and assign connected wireless devices an address in the 192.169.1.x range.

What I want to achieve is connect a physical computer to the RPi on its ethernet port and also have it assigned an address on the same network.

Is that possible?

Basically I want the RPi to function as if it were a router with some ethernet ports on it.

This would then show wlan0 and eth0 interfaces as being assigned an address in the 192.169.1.x range. My wlan0 interface currently has a static IP.

Answer (score 1):

To have the access point and the ethernet port using the same ip address range, means using the same subnet, you have to setup a bridge `br0` and then add as members the interfaces `eth0` and `wlan0`.

Because you are already use `hostapd` and `dnsmasq` you may have a look at [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point in a standalone network (NAT)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) how to do it with this programs.

If you like to configure it with built-in components then you should have a look at [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866), section **Setting up an access point with a bridge**.